# Einstein solid: one or three dimensional quantum harmonic oscillator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, solid-state-physics, lattice-model

The Einstein model for solids assumes all atoms vibrate with the same frequency $\omega$, each atom being modeled as a quantum harmonic oscillator. The thing is: solids are three-dimensional objects, hence the atoms vibrate in three dimensions.

This is addressed by doing the following:

The one-dimensional quantum harmonic oscillator has energy:

$$E_n = \left(n + \frac{1}{2} \right) \hbar \omega$$

*But since the quantum harmonic oscillator is three-dimensional, we may take the atoms as oscillating independently in each of the three dimensions:*

$$E_{nx} = \left(n_x + \frac{1}{2} \right) \hbar \omega$$

$$E_{ny} = \left(n_y + \frac{1}{2} \right) \hbar \omega$$

$$E_{nz} = \left(n_z + \frac{1}{2} \right) \hbar \omega$$

We then find the total energy of the solid $E(\omega, T)$ by using Boltzmann statistics independently in each direction, thus finding some energy $E_x$ for a given direction and then we find the total energy $E = 3E_x$, thus we find a heat capacity of $\frac{dE}{dT} = 3 \frac{dE_x}{dT}$.

What I'm in doubt about is that I tried to solve this same problem but by considering the atom as the three dimensional quantum harmonic oscillator of energy:

$$E_{n} = \left(n + \frac{3}{2} \right) \hbar \omega$$

And then solving for the total energy. What we find for the heat capacity using Boltzmann statistics here is the *same as the heat capacity if the oscillator was just one-dimensional*. This of course is wrong, since a factor of 3 is missing.

What I want to understand is why we use three "one-dimensional quantum harmonic oscillators" instead of one three-dimensional oscillator. I mean, I believe that what I have done wrong is not considering the degeneracy, but I'm not sure if that's really it. Does it have anything to do with $n = n_x + n_y + n_z$? If not, then what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A problem of finding a partition function of three similar noninteracting oscillators is a simple one. Due to the absence of interaction we have
$$
Z_3 = (Z_1)^3,
$$
where $Z_1$ is the partition function of one oscillator
$$
Z_1 = \sum_{n_x=0}^\infty e^{-\frac{\hbar\omega}{\theta}(n_x+1/2)}.
$$
Energy levels of a three-dimensional oscillator are degenerate indeed. The degeneracy of a level with the energy
$$
E_n = \hbar\omega(n+3/2)
$$
is equal to
$$
\Gamma_n = \sum_{n_x,n_y,n_z \geq 0} \Delta(n-n_x-n_y-n_z) = \frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2},
$$
where $\Delta(x) = 1$ if $x=0$  and $\Delta(x) = 0$ if $x\neq 0$. Due to this relation we still have
$$
Z_3 = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \Gamma_n e^{-\frac{\hbar\omega}{\theta}(n+3/2)} = (Z_1)^3,
$$
but the latter equality is not so obvious now. It holds because of the discrete delta-function in the expression for $\Gamma_n$.

Comment: Thank you. I've read some more on the partition function and I had misunderstood the Boltzmann distribution. This answer really enlightened me.